# When the return type is a class, what's the name of the pointer to the return value?

Tags: c++, pointers

An example:

---

```
class A  
{  
    ....  
    A func();  
};  

A A::func()  
{  
...  
return something;  
}
```

---

At assembly level, when compiled, the function `A::func` will actually have two parameters: the first one is the `this` pointer, and the second one is the address of a temp `A` object, created by the caller to store the return value.

For example, if we write `a.func()`, the program will create a temp `A` object (let's call it `t`) in the stack, and pass the address of `a` as first parameter, the address of `t` as second parameter, finally call the function `func`.

Here is my question: in the realization of `A::func`, we can get the address of `a` - it's the pointer `this`; but do we have a way to get the address of `t`? What's its name?

It will be useful to have it if, for example, I would like to do some memory alloc/free before returning the result.

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
class A
{
    int * data;
    A func();
};

A A::func()
{
    // here "ret_p" is the pointer to the return value (let's pretend that it exists)  
    ret_p->data = new int[some length];  
    ...  
    return * ret_p;  
}
```

Of course, I can create a local object in `A::func` and then return it; but then the program will do a copy between my local object and the temp object created by the caller. Since the caller already created a temp object, I'm hoping that I can save both time and space by just using it directly. Is that possible?

Well this is maybe out of c++, but I'm still hoping...

Comment: No, there is no such thing. The implementation does not even have to handle the return value in the way you describe.

Comment: Er, this is what the copy constructor is for. Use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supplying of `&a` to `func` is a form of [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision).

There is no guarantee that will happen at all, and no C++ level access to the implementation.

I don't think you're clear in your own head when you say "I would like to do some memory alloc/free before returning the result", can you give a specific example? Probably everything you need is made possible by copy elision, move operators, and RAII.

---

Responding to your example, here's how you should do it.

```
class A
{
    std :: vector <int> data;
    A func();
};

A A::func()
{
    A ret;
    ret .data .assign (some_length, 123); // or whatever;
    return ret;
}
```

This will *probably* optimise the way you want automatically due to copy elision. If you think the compiler won't elide the copy, add a move constructor.

```
A :: A (A && old)
: data (std :: move (old .data))
{
}
```

`std::vector`'s move constructor will simply copy the pointer. If you want to know how *that* works, well here's the homegrown equivalent.

```
class A
{
    int * data;

    // Allocate
    A (size_t size) : data (new int [size]) {}

    // Free, only if we haven't moved.
    ~ A () {if (data) delete [] data;}

    // Move
    A (A && old) : data (old .data) {old .data = nullptr;}

    A (const A &) = delete; // or implement with a new allocation.
}
```

Comment: I've added an example in my post

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I finally find the easiest way to optimise this: return the object as a reference. `A & func()` works fine, the caller doesn't create a temp object any more, it's the responsibility of the callee now. And when optimized we have the right copy elision as expected.

Comment: No. Return values, you can get into trouble returning references. It's always safer and sometimes *more* efficient. Trust the compiler and [read this](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/value-semantics/).

Comment: I quite understand your suggestion, because usually the reference returned will be a reference of some local variable of the callee, which lives in the stack and becomes destroyed if other functions are called. That's why the caller always creates an object for saving the result. But in my case I can control everything well, by always returning objects created in the heap - this saves the stack space (as well as the time for copying). It really works better.

Comment: Before making claims like that, you need to profile your code. Heap allocations are a lot more expensive than stack allocations.

Comment: Yes of course, but stack is precious, right? If we want more iterations etc... Also I can do other small tricks to make the heap allocation more effective. Anyway, I understand that the decision should be made carefully.

Comment: If you have recursion to a depth of thousands, yes, otherwise no. Test your program on realistic production situations and if the stack doesn't exhaust in testing then stay away from this. You're micro-optimising. Use value semantics, move operators, and trust the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a temp `A` object parameter (`t`) in the stack.

If you call `A a1 = a.func();` and `return something;` inside, the `copy constructor` will be called, equivalent to this `A a1(something);`. The `a1` and `something` are different instances.

If you `A a1; a1 = a.func();` and `return something;` inside, the `a1 = something; // (operator =)` will be called. The `a1` and `something` are different instances.

If you call `A a1 = a.func();` and `return A(p1);` inside, this is equivalent to `A a1(p1);`, there is one instance `a1`.

If you call `a.func();` directly without assigning to a var and `return something;` inside, nothing happens when return.

If you call `a.func();` directly without assigning to a var and `return A(p1);` inside, a temp object will be constructed and then destroyed immediately.

If you `A a1; a1 = a.func();` and `return A(p1);` inside, a temp object will be constructed, and then operator= will be called `a1 = temp object;` and then the temp object will be destroyed.

For your reference.

After all, `A a1 = a.func()` or `A a1; a1 = a.func()`, `return something; // a var` or `return A(p1); // call constructor` will cause different behaviors, I think you can control memory correctly.

Comment: This is not what's happening when I check the disassembled code. I should mention that I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. I'm quite sure that the caller leaves space for a local `A` object in the stack and use it to store the return value - at least in "debug" mode. In "release" mode this step sometimes is skipped due to optimization, but for complicated codes the temp object still exists in stack. You other descriptions are correct.